# How to count cells that have conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a spreadsheet that keeps track of projects that includes a target date column and an actual date column. The actual date columns have been conditionally formatted to turn red or green if they meet the target date or white if N/A has been entered. Green is <=Target Date and Red is >Target Date.

I am trying to create metrics for these dates to see on time delivery etc. So I have the COUNT(Target Date) function to count the dates that have been entered which omits empty cells and cells with N/A. But I'm stuck on how to count cells that have turned green for on time delivery. I have tried the COUNTIF function and using the same rules (<=) as the conditional formatting to count the cells, but it is just returning with 0.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Adding some sample data, and exactly what your countif-formulas look like would make it easier to help you. From what you are describing, I can't see why your approach isn't working.

Comment: Use the same conditions for the countif() or countifs() that you use for the conditional formatting, should work fine.

Comment: Normal Excel formulas cannot count cells based on colors. That must be done with VBA. But your colors come from a Conditional formatting rule `white if N/A has been entered. Green is <=Target Date and Red is >Target Date.` So you can count with normal formulas which cells meet those requirements, as @SolarMike suggested.

Comment: @eirikdaude unsure how to post sample data but here are formulas:
=COUNT(Pilot[PO Actual Date]) - total counts for dates entered on the actual date column
=COUNTIF(Pilot[PO Actual Date],"<=" & Pilot[PO Target Date]) - attempts at counting on time dates.

Comment: How is your PO Target Date formatted? Are they actually dates or text looking like dates? If they are text it would explain returning 0. It would be interesting to see how your formatting formulas look like to know why they turn green.

Comment: @JvdV they are a custom format of dates dd-mmm-yy.

Answer (score 0):

The `Range` object has an attribute `FormatConditions`, which keeps the conditional formatting definitions. You can check this, using VBA. I don't think it's possible reading this using a simple formula.