# How to count cells with a specific cell format containing zero?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to count only cells containing zero **with a specific cell format**?

Take this list: A1 through A10 all contains zero. Cells A1, A4 and A5 of this range have a cell format which shows *zeros as stars(*)*. Now, I'd like to count these three cells, stars.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, there's no native functions that return cell formatting. Meaning you'll need to make a UDF using vba.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,0)` if the value of the cell is 0. It does not matter the formating, if not try `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*")`